# How to define and use common values inside multiple model properties in dbt

Tags: dbt

I have model properties file defined in .yml and query defined in .sql. There are many models and there are some properties which are shared across models. So for instance I have used `meta` tag in .yml model property file and need to define a value let say a: . Now this  is used across multiple model meta's. How can I define and use t hem in the dbt model properties file?

Answer (score 0):

Variables not only works in .sql but also works in .yml in the model properties file. Here one sample of it

https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/pull/2015

works